# Quick way to remove similar results from MySQL results

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

A website that I run has a problem with duplicate content being posted by its users. As a result when visitors search for content, it returns what appears to be some results that are exactly the same.

The issue is that the duplicate content isn't carbon copy. There may be a word changed here and there, or it'll be posted a couple of days later but the additional results are not needed as they are essentially a re-post.

An example would be:

> Title: Trousers for sale Description: I am selling a pair of trousers.
>   They have holes in them. Contact Rob on 1234
>
> Title: Trousers for sale Description: I am selling a pair of trousers.
>   They have some holes in them. Contact Rob
>
> Title: My Trousers for sale Description: I am selling a pair of
>   trousers. They have holes in them. Contact Rob on 1234

Is there some form of algorithm (preferably built-in to PHP and fast) that could fish out these duplicates with decent accuracy? It will be searching through a result set of about 50 items, each with up to 500 characters of text.

EDIT: I should also add that the similar results may not be next to each other, so I cant simply compare the current result to the previous one. In an ideal world it would be something like SELECT title, desc FROM database WHERE id IN (10,40,54,143,444) AND UNIQUE(title,desc) > 90%.

Comment: you could use regex to see how many words match and if it's more than say 90% flag it for review / deletion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget my reply above and use the following code:

```
    class similarText
    {
        private $arrayResults = array();
        private $text;

        public function test( $text, $accepted_percentage = 70 )
        {
            if( count( $this->arrayResults ) )
            {
              foreach( $this->arrayResults as $result )
              {
                similar_text( $result, $text, $percent );

                if( ( (int) $percent ) >= $accepted_percentage )
                {
                  $this->save( $text );
                  return (int) $percent;
                }
              }
            }
            $this->save( $text );
            return 0;
        }

        private function save( $text )
        {
            $this->arrayResults[ $text ] = $text;
        }
    }


    $similar = new similarText();

    while( /*[ $fetch = ... ]*/ )
    {
        $title = $fetch['title'];
        $description = $fetch['description'];

        if( $similar->test( $title, 70 ) || $similar->test( $description, 70 ) )
        {
          continue;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this

[Levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)

It calculates how many insert deletes and replace you need to make the strings equal.

You would need to do this after your results from the database.

Then you pick an arbitrary number like 50 to compare the distances between each string. Now since this is done using only 2 string you would need to run a loop to compare each string and I'm not sure how many results you have ( no data) so it would be hard to say how efficiently it runs or not.

The levenshtein runs in O(m*n) which are the lengths of the strings and if you compare that against each string it might be costly but it would be hard to get it faster.

If you can provide a more complete sample of results it would help. As in are all the results similar posts like you show or are there other results mixed in.

Maybe you can split the sql statement to get similar results and run the levenshtein on those?

Comment: if you know your results are all similar you can do a simple word count with str_word_count()

Answer (score 0):

Leave me understand you, you don't want show similar results?

You can use **similar_text**

Exemple:

```
$ArrayResults = array();
$found = 0;
$accepted_percentage = 70;

while( /*[ $fetch = ... ]*/ )
{
    $title = $fetch['title'];
    if( count( $ArrayResults ) )
    {
      foreach( array_unique( $ArrayResults ) as $result )
      {
        similar_text( $result, $title, $percent );
        if( $percent >= $accepted_percentage )
        {
          $found = 1;
        }
      }
    }
    if( $found )
    {   
      $found = 0;
      continue;
    }
    $ArrayResults[ $title ] = $title;
}
```

Comment: That looks interesting, I didn't know about similar_text. However, am I right in saying that this snippet only compares the current result with the previous one?

Comment: @James Napier: It's not compare only last results, but all results into the loop.

Comment: Ahh yes I didn't notice the last line. Problem is that as I'm going to be comparing title and description, if I put that all into $ArrayResults[$titleanddesc] isn't it going to choke when the test is up to 500chars long?